# sql- move each date to 1st day of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to take every date to the first day of the month. For example if I have:
20140103 I need to have 20140101
I thought a good idea could be loaddate - difference between loaddate and 1st date and I wrote:

```
loaddate- DATEdiff(day, day(loaddate),loaddate)
```

But the result is wrong. How can I solve this???

Thanks

Comment: you mean turn `2014-09-08` into `2014-09-01`? `date_format(datefield, '%Y-%m-01')`, assuming mysql.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server You can do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(loaddate)-1),loaddate),101)
```

For:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GetDATE()),101)
```

You will get back: `09/01/2014`